# Changing Reference Voltage A/D on Microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, microchip

I am using a microcontroller PIC18F4550. It has a reference voltage from 0 - 3.3 volts for the A/D converters.

I had two questions:

1) If the voltage drops below 0 (negative), will the A/D converter report the negative value?

2) Is there anyway to change the reference voltage, either by adding an additional circuit or by manipulating it by code?

Thank you!

Comment: The code for the Microcontroller is in C and I thought it might be possible to manipulate the code. Thank you. I should post my question there?

Comment: It is easier to manipulate the code if it is _posted_.  Your question borders on both EE and CS issues, best to focus on the C issues here (show your code) and the EE issues there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If the voltage drops below zero you could damage the chip, so don't let that happen. Absolute maximum ratings on the device say -0.3V is the lowest you should go.
2. You can add an external reference on AN3 and AN2 by the look of it. If you check out the datasheet it shows that usually the reference is Vdd, but you can connect it to external pins instead. You'll have to change a register in software to use that external reference.  All this is  standard stuff for micros.